# Attempting to read portion of HTML file with curl and the output is strange

Tags: php, curl

```
set_time_limit(0);
$ch = curl_init('http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=highscores&world=Antica');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, '0-999');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
echo $data = curl_exec($ch);//get curl response
curl_close($ch);
```

And the example output is (it is slightly different every time I hit refresh button):
    ‹í]kSã8ºþNÕü­OÍÕr™&™‚ ³ÜÒ3{æ¥8J¢Æ±2¾é=ûßÏ«‹Û±BãYÜåž,[¥÷òHz%[ÎÁØ›XÖÆàˆÐG=‹tz´O1ª S‡té[ZxF    tm[Ô&è–YÝÀ%jÐ'¿½?¿<ütrÇË‹_X_BD1‡Ýîõç«^¤œàŠ(Èå%ÓwH¤$lšÌ·½°¨Ñý)s&W¼‰­Ç¯Rb ¢‰Ð{dÐª      zp×½=¿é¡ÞÿÞœ,úµ³vð·JU«0D@EÔ²ˆ³æ¯G'„A{Û0Ì1tjä´ÜØ4þŽšµZmóãÚÐ·MÞÆQ4{íßà=:DSì@³ß    ò2Ý-‹Ø#oŒ:¨±     ‰þ-üË1}‡=¹ÄéÍ¦¨ÝF%F‹ºßb²#i˜éO¢W> à]Ã»\b ·<6]~ßÿÿ?k v¥&¨JuÖÖÞ®PB)¶èWm ƒÁþ~}¿ÖÜÛö÷wš ÒØ®Õ04IØÜ!õdS€1½ªuHö

The page is displayed correctly when I comment out CURLOPT_RANGE

EDIT: I added 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
The output seems to be okay, but only when the range starts with 0. If the range is for example 2000-3000, it outputs completely nothing.

EDIT 2: The error message is: "Error while processing content unencoding: invalid distance too far back"

Comment: I'd bet you're getting gzipped content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used CURLOPT_RANGE. Is there a reason you need to use this?

The reason gzip only works when you start from 0 is there is information there that it needs to unzip the content. If you must use Range then you should capture the data for each range and combine it and then un-gzip that.

EDIT:

You mention in some comments that you use Range to get some of the data to save bandwidth. I checked the page using Firebug and it's < 10kb. With all the images it's almost 500k. You are already saving quite a bit and unless you're using dial-up internet 10kb it's nothing. Don't worry about using Range and combining the chunks, just let cURL handle the gzip.

Comment: Agreed, though with the small modification that any gzipped content will need to be downloaded in full in order to decode properly, so there would be no need to gather different ranges and then attempt to combine them.

Comment: I want to use it, because I only need to open a certain porion of data from many pages that look like this and it's not necessary to download entire page. How can I combine ranges?

Comment: Yeah, although there would be no gain vs file_get_contents. Something is taking a lot of my data through apache and I thought it could be the case but you just enlightened me that it's not the case most likely.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting gzipped content. You should explicitly state that you want plain HTML returned. You can add the following option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'deflate');
```